# Where to download repositories after Bintray sunset as the bintray link responds with Forbidden

Tags: maven, dependencies, artifactory, bintray

Recently I heard about bintray sunset starting 1st May 2021. How can I download the artifacts hosted on bintray?

For example, I want to download https://github.com/americanexpress/nodes/ which is hosted on https://dl.bintray.com/americanexpress/maven.

When I open https://dl.bintray.com/americanexpress/maven/io/aexp/nodes/graphql/parent/0.5.0 it responds with forbidden, which I believe would be due to sunset of bintray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically - this artifact can be found on other repositories.

See search on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.aexp.nodes.graphql/nodes?repo=atlassian-packages-3rdparty).

In other cases, where the modules are not found, you should contact the developer or project owner asking for the new location of the module. They might need to publish it.